# How to find the Wold Representation for ARMA(2,2)?

Tags: time-series, arima

[image]

Consider the ARMA(2,2) process given by
$$
X_t=0.4X_{t-1}+0.45X_{t-2}+e_t+e_{t-1}+0.25e_{t-1} \quad \text{with} \quad e_t\sim WN(0,\sigma_e^2).
$$
Obtain the Wold Representation of $X_t$.

I am confused about this question, especially the Wold Representation. Can I answers it as followes?

[image]

Comment: Please type the question and your attempted solution instead of posting a screenshot. We have blind users who answer questions here, and their screen readers won’t help them if the content is in a screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function#Taylor_series?  Also, you need to take into consideration that your AR and MA polynomials have a common root.

Comment: Hi: what you were doing is fine. But don't do the very last line. Simply cancel out the (1 + 0.5L) in the top and bottom ( of the next to last line ) and then further simplify by multiplying both sides by (1-0.9L). That will give you the ARMA(1,1). Then, once you have the ARMA(1,1), the wold representation, atleast for this case, just means convert it to a pure MA like you were doing.